# How to start program B when program A starts and terminates?

Tags: windows

Program A is a large program, such as a game, a working software, and program B is a small program, which is used to change some system settings. Now I want program A to run program B both at startup and at termination.
I tried to use Windows Task Scheduler to solve this problem, but I ran into difficulties, I can't set custom event filters.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put both in a batchfile, like in this simple example:

```
start "First B program" Program_B
start Program_A
start "Second B program" Program_B
```

The `start` command will open a window (if needed) and launch the program inside that window. It will then wait for that program to have terminated for starting the next one. (Don't use `call`: this won't wait)

Comment: But program A was called by another program, and I did not modify the program that called A.